# Перестала работать загрузка файлов в Alfresco

Tags: java, smtp, alfresco

Здравствуйте, после установки последней версии расширения Alvex для Alfresco Community 5.1 перестала работать загрузка файлов в репозиторий сайта. В логе Alfresco при попытке загрузки появляются следующие ошибки:

```
Failed to send email to user : org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.example.com, 25; timeout -1;
ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-apr-8080-exec-9] Exception from executeScript: 03020169 Failed to execute transaction-level behaviour public abstract void org.alfresco.repo.version.VersionServicePolicies$AfterCreateVersionPolicy.afterCreateVersion(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,org.alfresco.service.cmr.version.Version) in transaction 54a77a6c-1c8e-45cf-8283-b80358d71673
```

Сами настройки Alfresco оставлены по-умолчанию.

Конечно можно настроить почтовый сервер для отправки уведомлений, но мне он не нужен. Можно ли как-то отключить отправку уведомлений, чтобы Alfresco не пытался отправить уведомление через SMTP сервер по-умолчанию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После некоторого поиска нашел решение в [блоге](http://ru.blog.itdhq.com/post/135760637810/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-alfresco-51-alfresco-inform) создателей расширения Alvex. Проблема была с модулем Alvex inform policy extension, входящим в состав Alvex, который слал сообщения на почту при каждом действии с документами. Для того, чтобы отключить отправку сообщений модулем нужно добавить следующий строки в Alfresco-global.properties:

```
documentchangeinform.creator=false
documentchangeinform.lasteditor=false
documentchangeinform.associated=false
documentchangeinform.editors=false
documentchangeinform.infavorites=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Здесь 2 варианта решения проблемы:

1. Настроить подключение к почтовому серверу и добавить в `alfresco-global.properties` все, что нужно для работы Alvex Inform Policy. Список настроек: https://github.com/ITDSystems/alvex-inform-policy-extension#use
2. Обновите Alvex до сборки позднее 15.06.2017. Тогда была исправлена [проблема](https://github.com/ITDSystems/alvex-inform-policy-extension/issues/10) с загрузкой файла при ненастроенном подключении к почте.

P.S. Вообще такие баги лучше заводить как issue на Github, а то я вот только нашла тут такой вопрос. :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно отключить уведомления  в настройках профиля пользователя.
Или в /opt/alfresco-community/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties стоит настроить рабочий  smtp для отправки.
Есть конечно третий вариант закомментировать куски кода, которые отвечают за отправку, но я не нашёл этих мест в файлах проекта.

Comment: Тоже думал, что надо настроить SMTP. Но у меня Alfresco используется в локальной сети без выхода в интернет. Вот и думаю, может есть какой-нибудь параметр, который надо добавить в alfresco-global.properties, чтобы отключить SMTP. Мне вообще не понятно, откуда он берет хост и порт, потому что в моих настройках эти параметры не указаны.